# Pass variable to another page and refresh default page [php]

Tags: php

I have a variable on index page, I want to pass it to script page. The script page has only php code which I want to trigger with variable passed. So basically I don't want browser to navigate to script page I just want to bring that code into action. I am doing so with the help of form.

index.php

```
echo "<form action='script.php' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='var' value=".$var." />
<input type='submit' value='Function'/>
</form>";
```

Here though the code on script is triggered but I am navigated to script page which I don't want. I want the `index.php` to be reloaded on passing variable. How can I do that without any javascript code or header in script.php ?

Comment: its not possible without js.

Comment: Best way is to implement Ajax. Otherwise you will need to navigate to script page then redirect back to index page.